# Elasticsearch Delete Query By Date

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I'm running the following query :

```
q='{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter": {
            "and": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "creation_time": {
                         "from": "2012-08-30",
                                    "to": "2012-08-31",

                                "include_lower": true,
                                "include_upper": true
                        }
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```

My domain is an ec2 server

```
curl -XDELETE "http://#{mydomain}:9200/monitoring/mention_reports/_query?q=#{q}"
```

When I am hitting this query it gives me

> curl: (3) [globbing] nested braces not supported at pos 118

Please help me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re trying to exec `curl` from the command line, it should be looking like:

```
q='YOUR_QUERY_CODE_GOES_HERE' 
curl -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" \
     -XDELETE -d $q http://localhost:9200/monitoring/mention_reports/_query
```

In case of inside-ruby execution, you should format the request as you do, but the silver bullet is still in headers:

```
-H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"
```